# sweetalert2 changing popup icon colour

Tags: css, sass, sweetalert2

I'm trying to change the [SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/) popup icon colour for swal2-error.

I've changed the variable colour in the node package for it, & put the variable in both my components scss & my global scss file, & it won't change worst part is if I go into the inspect element & change the colour there on the

```
.swal2-icon.swal2-error {
    border-color: #f27474;
}
```

It will change but again mimick that css in all the relevant files & nothing changes, any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding `!important` to override any other color definitions you might have.

```
.swal2-icon.swal2-error {
  border-color: #f27474 !important;
}
```

Comment: You my friend are a legend, I'll be honest I've never encountered the !important keyword before I shall look into this now.

Answer (score 4):

since the [latest versions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65159547/11675758) of SweetAlert2, the option to control the color of the icon is available by using the value `iconColor` :

```
swal.fire({
    title: 'your title',
    icon: 'success',
    iconColor: '#30a702',
    showCloseButton: true
});
```